# Do the same for every part in listdlg (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I am writing a program and I am using `listdlg`.  I want for each selection of the list to do the same thing BUT it will save them in different part(so that every option will have it's own - let's say- sub folder with its text files and they can be accessed for another function.

So this is my `listdlg`

`global fileCount`

```
F = listdlg('PromptString','Different types', 'SelectionMode',...
    'single', 'ListString',{E}, 'Name','Select a type','ListSize',[230 130]);
```

where `{E}` is user's input, which might be 3 rows or 6 rows, how many he likes.

So I want if he uses the first row to ask for input and then save it for the first type

```
 if F == 1
        [file,path] = uigetfile ('*.txt','Select your text files',...
            'MultiSelect','on');
        file = cellstr(file);   
            for k = 1:length(file)
                fileCount = length (file);                    
                z = importdata(fullfile(path, file{k}));
            end
   end
```

the same will be done for the following types, meaning if he chooses the 2nd then the files will be saved for the 2nd file, but the files of the first type will not be overwrote. So he now has let's say Orange-10files; Pink-2files and Yellow-4files.

Is there a way I can do that? except using `if` and `elseif` for every of his choice?

I hope I was clear enough!

Thanks!

Comment: Is `E` supposed to contain the folder names? Because then it's a simple call to `fullfile(path,E{F},file{k})` to get the save directory for each file. No need for a `switch` or `if/elseif` statement.

Comment: E is suppose to be: Orange, Pink, Yellow etc etc.. whatever the user decides.. so it will be just a `for` loop `k=1:lenght(file)` and that bit you wrote?

Comment: when I am adding the `E{F}` I get an error saying `Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.`

Answer (score 1):

Assign `E` as a cell array rather than inserting it as a cell array in the `listdlg` call. I'm not entirely clear on your end goal, but this will take the user's selection of E's elements, open whatever files the user selects, and return the path and file name of those files with the added "color" folder:

```
E = {'Orange','Pink','Yellow'};
F = listdlg('PromptString','Different types', 'SelectionMode',...
    'single', 'ListString',E, 'Name','Select a type','ListSize',[230 130]);
[files,path] = uigetfile ('*.txt','Select your text files',...
            'MultiSelect','on');   
files = cellfun(@(x) fullfile(path,E{F},x),files,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: thanks but I have used a hashtable instead.. :) thanks anywway! :)